# Can't get right with IPv6

Tags: linux, ipv6

I got an IPv6-Subet `1009:2417:25:41::/64` - the first ip should be the gateway - is `1009:2417:25:41::1` right? Can you give me a Site or a tutorial how to get the first 100 Host-IPs? (I think some of them should `1009:2417:25:41::2`, `1009:2417:25:41::3`, `1009:2417:25:41::4` ...)

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure your IPs start with a 1009::? Maybe 2001::?

Either way, you can use any IP addresses you want, in a way you find appropriate (=easiest to remember).

```
1009:2417:25:41::2
1009:2417:25:41::3
...
1009:2417:25:41::101
```

Will work just fine, although

```
1009:2417:25:41::0
1009:2417:25:41::1
...
1009:2417:25:41::9
1009:2417:25:41::a
1009:2417:25:41::b
...
1009:2417:25:41::f
1009:2417:25:41::10
...
1009:2417:25:41::63
```

Are the first 100 addresses. IPv6 addresses are written in hexadecimal.

Just try not to use the [EUI-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64)-like addresses (those with FF FE in the middle of the "right part"), since with some bad luck, you might have a collision with a self-generated address.

Comment: It is most likely going to be 2001, 2009 hasn't been assigned yet - http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments.xml

Comment: Didn't even look at the assignment list, 2009:: atleast starts with a 001(binary), while 1009:: doesn't. Edited.

Comment: It all depends on your preferences. We use the last 8 bits of an ipv4 address, so if the ipv4 address is 1.2.3.123, the ipv6 address is 2001:DB8::123 (easier for the admins to remember).

Comment: No my Subnet didn't start with 2009 - I edited the address - for privacy reason ...